# How we can remove value of "<a>" tag when the page has loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<ul class="filter-list">
<li class="filter">
<select class="field" name="field">
<select class="exclude" name="exclude">
<input class="value" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="*:*" name="value">
<a class="action remove-filter disabled" title="remove">
<span>remove</span>
</a>
<a class="action add-filter" title="add another">add another</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove "add another" value of  tag when the page has loaded.. How can we do this.. Any suggestions??

Comment: What do you mean by "when the page has loaded"?

Comment: 2 people can't both be the `accepted answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(doucument).ready(function(){
         $('.add-filter').html("");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly:

```
$('.add-filter').remove(); //removes the <a> tag

$('.add-filter').empty(); //removes the html inside the <a> tag
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the text inside the `a` element:

`$('a.action.add-filter').text('');`

To remove the whole element:

```
$('a.action.add-filter').remove();
```

You need to wrap it inside a DOM ready, like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('a.action.add-filter').text('');
});
```